# Ruby delete values from multi dimensional array

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have some arrays that I put into one array called `alist[]`. I am iterating over the array to print out all values of `alist[]`. I need to find a value at `alist[2][i]` and then remove the `alist[0][i]`, `alist[1][i]`, `alist[2][i]`, `alist[3][i]`, `alist[4][i]` from my array `alist[][]`. (I removed the code that fills my arrays so it is easier to read my question)

This is my best guess below but it is not working. Would anyone have any ideas?

```
#declare arrays
nsymbol = []
sname = []
etf = []
testv = []
financials = []
alist = []

#create one array with all other arrays
alist.push(nsymbol, sname, etf, testv, financials)

(0...nsymbol.length).each do |i|
  (0...alist.length).each do |j|
    if (alist[2][i] || '').include? 'Y'
      alist.delete_at(0)
      alist.delete_at(1)
      alist.delete_at(2)
      alist.delete_at(3)
      alist.delete_at(4)
    end
    #print whole array out
    puts alist[j][i]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By performing `alist.delete_at(0)` you delete the first item of `alist` so to speak `alist[0][0..N]` but you want to delete `alist[0][i]` so you need to delete the i*th* item of `alist[0]`.

```
alist[0].delete_at(i)
alist[1].delete_at(i)
# etc.
```

Because you are printing your array just after deleting the new contents it doesn't matter, but if you want to use the array after this you should break the loop after deleting the entries, because deleting the entries leads to another entry now being the item `alist[2][i]` and eventually to a  further deletion of the entries. (Though this might also be exactly what you want).

Comment: Yes it is exactly what I was looking for. Then I'm gonna dump `alist[]` into another array that will be the correct size